SwipeToDismiss in a horizontalPager?
I have a problem: I have an WearOs application in which I use a SiwpeDissmissableNavHost To navigate between views. One Of those views contains a PagerScreen (or a HorizontalPager) with ScalingLazyColumns inside.
The Problem is, that even though, I enclosed the Pager in a SwipeToDismissBox and has a edgeSwipeToDismiss() modifier, the Swiping gesture doesn't work correctly.
Whenever I do the Swipe-To-Dismiss-gesture. I don't go to the homescreen, as I want, but instead to another view, which looks exactly like the one I just dismissed. It somehow seems, like a copy of this view is launched behind the current one and when I try to dismiss it, I get redirected to the previous one. But this view seems to be pretty buggy, because it is half-Stuck between to pages.
Here is a Video for better explanation.....
